# Aligning a tile to bottom of another tile

Tags: html, css

I'm building a user interface where I'm using metro style tiles. I've tried placing a tile on another tile but for some reason, I'm not able to align this second tile to the bottom of the first tile.
This is how it looks right now: http://jsfiddle.net/44GQk/1/

Can anyone tell me how to align the black tile to the bottom of the blue one?
This is the CSS code:

```
.tile {  
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;       
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.blue 
{   
    background:#336E7B;
}
.black
{  
    background:#4DAF7C;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="tile blue box-alignment">
    <div align="center">
        <h2 class="icon-white">User Name</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tile black" style="width:100%;margin-bottom:0px;padding:5px;background-color:rgba(26,26,26,255);opacity:0.7;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you expect them to line up on the page; you don't need to use absolute positioning.

Here's an update that I did: http://jsfiddle.net/44GQk/4/

Html:

```
<div class="tile blue box-alignment">
    <div align="center">
        <h2 class="icon-white">User Name</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- move the second tile outside of the first tile -->
<div class="tile black" style="margin-bottom:0px;padding:5px;background-               
                               color:rgba(26,26,26,255);opacity:0.7;">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tile {  
    width: 75%;
    /*display: inline-block; this causes space between the tiles and removes block 
            behavior of the div. 75% width on two elements causes wrapping, anyway.*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;       
    padding: 20px;
    /*margin-bottom: 30px;  this causes space between the tiles.*/
}
.blue 
{   
    background:#336E7B;
}
.black
{  
    background:#4DAF7C;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute` :

```
.tile {  
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;       
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;  /* required */
}
.blue 
{   
    background:#336E7B;
}
.black
{ 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background:#4DAF7C;
}
```

But if your goal is simply to get a border, I would recommend to use this code :

```
<div class="tile blue box-alignment">
    <div align="center">
        <h2 class="icon-white">User Name</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.tile {  
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;       
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(26,26,26,.7);
}
.blue 
{   
    background:#336E7B;
}
```

Comment: No, I was not looking for a border for the tile,I actually wanted to display some text in it. And the positioning did not work either, it actually messed up the whole layout :p